# check for never[] in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a react-component that should list the images that user is uploading.
When user has not.

```
const [imageList, setImageList] = useState([]); 
const BlaLabel = () => (!imageList || imageList.length === 0) ? "No image loaded" : "Image(s) loaded";
return(<>...<BlaLabel/>...</>)
```

this does not work, the text "Image(s) loaded" is displayed before user has done anything. Some observations:

- typeof(imageList) is 'object'
- the typescript-type of imageList is'never[]'
- JSON.stringify(imageList) is '[]'.

If I add

```
|| imageList === []
```

to the condition it all works fine and dandy. But my problem is that I don't really understand...

Is **never[]** an object which stringifies to '[]'. Is this yet another check I need to do to 'null' and 'undefined'? What is the difference between  **a === []** and **a.length === 0**. When googling this, it doesnt seems to be a big problem for anyone, so hopefully Im mistunderstanding somehting.

In short. How do I correctly check is imageList (above) is not set

Comment: To avoid unset types in TypeScript when defining arrays replace your `[]` with `new Array<string>()` (for e.g. an string array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first error I got, was that the strings you try to type are not JSX elements, but are required to be. So I wrapt `<p>`. At second added the `button` with `onClick()` to imitiate adding and check if the text changes.

```
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";

type ImageProps = {
  url?: string;
};

export default function App() {
  const [imageList, setImageList] = React.useState<ImageProps[]>([]);
  const BlaLabel = () =>
    !imageList || imageList.length === 0 ? (
      <p>No image loaded</p>
    ) : (
      <p>Image(s) loaded</p>
    );
  return (
    <>
      <BlaLabel />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setImageList((oldArray) => [...oldArray, { url: "/asd" }]);
        }}
      >
        Add Image
      </button>
    </>
  );
```

Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-hertz-prtre)

Comment: ok, thanks. This particular component has a .js-file, and maybe there is some confusion there. Thanks. (given code was just some freehand code, not the actual code)